# making the Makefile of rApache gives me errors

Tags: makefile, rapache

Apologize in advance, I am a newbie in Linux and these stuffs.

I have to install rApache 1.2.0, but when I write on the terminal:

```
make -f ~/Makefile.am
```

it gives me many errors, such as:

```
make: *** No rule to make target "mod_R.h", needed by "mod_R.so".
```

or

```
make: *** No rule to make target "@DOCROOT@/httpd.conf.in", needed by "@DOCROOT@/httpd.conf".
```

Here is the Makefile.am ([link](https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/rapache/blob/master/Makefile.am)):

```
# DARWIN has to be different than everyone else
# and define their autoconf $shlibpath_var to be DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
SHLIBPATH_VAR=@SHLIBPATH_VAR@

ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

APXS=@APXS@
HTTPD=@HTTPD@
DOCROOT=@DOCROOT@

APREQ=@APREQ@
APREQ_COMPILE=@APREQ_COMPILE@
APREQ_INSTALL=@APREQ_INSTALL@
APREQ_CLEAN=@APREQ_CLEAN@
APREQ_LIB_DIR=@APREQ_LIB_DIR@
APREQ_INCLUDES=@APREQ_INCLUDES@
APREQ_LINKLD=@APREQ_LINKLD@

RPROG=@RPROG@
RPROGBATCH=R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL @RPROG@ --vanilla --no-readline --slave -f
R_HOME = `$(RPROG) RHOME`
R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $(R_HOME)/lib
RINCLUDES=@RINCLUDES@
RLINKLD=@RLINKLD@

INCLUDES = $(RINCLUDES) $(APREQ_INCLUDES)
LDFLAGS = $(RLINKLD) $(APREQ_LINKLD)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(R_LD_LIBRARY_PATH):$(APREQ_LIB_DIR)
RPATH=@RPATH@

all: mod_R.so $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf

mod_R.so: .apreq-config mod_R.c mod_R.h
    @echo
    @echo Compiling mod_R
    @echo
    $(APXS) $(INCLUDES) -c mod_R.c $(RPATH) $(LDFLAGS)

.apreq-config:
    @echo
    @echo Configuring libapreq2
    @echo
    $(APREQ_COMPILE)
    touch .apreq-config

install: all
    $(APXS) -i -n R mod_R.la
    $(APREQ_INSTALL)

$(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf: $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf.in
    $(RPROGBATCH) tools/config_http.R --args $(APXS) $(HTTPD)

itest: all
    @echo
    @echo Point your browser to http://localhost:8181/index.html
    @echo
    $(SHLIBPATH_VAR)=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) R_HOME=$(R_HOME) $(HTTPD) -X -f $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf

test: all $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf

stop: all
    $(SHLIBPATH_VAR)=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) R_HOME=$(R_HOME) $(HTTPD) -X -f $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf -k stop

valgrind: all
    $(SHLIBPATH_VAR)=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) R_HOME=$(R_HOME) valgrind $(HTTPD) -X -f $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf

debug: all
    @echo
    @echo Copy/paste the following line to gdb
    @echo
    @echo run -X -f $(DOCROOT)/httpd.conf 
    @echo
    $(SHLIBPATH_VAR)=$(LD_LIBRARY_PATH) R_HOME=$(R_HOME) gdb $(HTTPD)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJS) core mod_R.o mod_R.so *~ .libs *.o *.slo *.lo *.la .apreq-config
    $(APREQ_CLEAN)

distclean: clean
    rm -rf mod_R.h Makefile .depend .install libtool config.log config.status test/httpd.conf test/access_log test/error_log test/httpd.pid test/accept.lock* aclocal.m4 autom4te.cache libapreq2/library/t/Makefile libapreq2/config.nice libapreq2/module/apache/Makefile
    $(APREQ_CLEAN)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Sho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

makefile.am is a template for autotools

makefile.am -> automake -> makefile.in

makefile.in -> autoconf -> Makefile

There must be an INSTALL or a README file.

Generally commands are

```
./configure
make
make test
make install
```

try `./configure --help` for options (--prefix if you are not admin)

Comment: so... how can I use makefile.in?

Comment: commands are `./configure`, `make`, `make install`. but I am stuck at make.